# Facebook Graph in login onSuccess execute and wait

Tags: android, multithreading, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to collect the user name and the profile picture after the user logged in. I need to do that in the login process, i tried that in the `onSuccess` Methode from the `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>` but it failed.

My Code:

```
btnFbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            final String authToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            // Facebook Name, Profile Picture
            /*GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            try {
                                userName = object.getString("name");
                                String url = object.getString("picture");

                                URL facebookProfileURL = new URL(url);
                                Bitmap profPict = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(facebookProfileURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
                                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                profPict.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

                                profilePicAsString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                                facebookAuthObject.setUserId(userId);
                                facebookAuthObject.setAuthToken(authToken);
                                facebookAuthObject.setName(userName);
                                facebookAuthObject.setProfilePictureAsString(profilePicAsString);
                            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "name, picture.width(150).height(150)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();*/


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i(TAG, "User cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

I need something like the `executeAndWait` but this is impossible because I'm on the main thread.

With this I have the problem that if the user leave the activity too fast i have nothing, because of the async.

Have anybody an idea how i can block the ui thread? Or other solutions for collecting the name and the profile picture?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Through this you can get the details from facebook

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

```
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            }
        };
        accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        final LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();

        loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {

                                        Log.v(TAG, "facebook login response: " + object.toString());
                                        try {
                                            email=object.getString("email");


                                            loginManager.logOut();
                                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MudraMainActivity.class));
                                            finish();

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }


                                    }
                                });

                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "email,name");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    }
                });

        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Same as in my code, if the user quickly leave the activity I have no user data.

Comment: Only in the onSuccess() method you will get the data.If the user leaves the process will not complete to get the data from facebook.

Comment: yes that's right but i need a dialog to block the thread. because the user logged in and then he leave the activity. the process has no chance to download the picture before the user leaves the activity. I need to collect the name and the profile picture before he leaves the activity.